# Loop through multiple variables and perform calculations

Tags: r, loops

I have the following DF:

```
structure(list(Company = c("Ferrari", "Ferrari", "Ferrari", "Lamborghini", 
"Lamborghini", "Lamborghini", "Lamborghini", "KTM", "KTM", "KTM", 
"KTM", "KTM", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT"), 
    Country = c("ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER", 
    "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", 
    "ESP", "ESP"), Value = c(23, 12, 45, 34, 56, 3, 1, 3, 12, 
    35, 45, 45, 3, 78, 23, 12, 2, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I want to run a loop so that it computes the sum across each variable "Company" and calculate then the share of each company for each country.

Something like:

```
structure(list(Company = c("Ferrari", "Ferrari", "Ferrari", "Lamborghini", 
"Lamborghini", "Lamborghini", "Lamborghini", "KTM", "KTM", "KTM", 
"KTM", "KTM", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT", "SEAT"), 
    Country = c("ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER", 
    "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", 
    "ESP", "ESP"), Value = c(23, 12, 45, 34, 56, 3, 1, 3, 12, 
    35, 45, 45, 3, 78, 23, 12, 2, 3), Share = c(0.2875, 0.15, 
    0.5625, 0.361702127659574, 0.595744680851064, 0.0319148936170213, 
    0.0106382978723404, 0.0214285714285714, 0.0857142857142857, 
    0.25, 0.321428571428571, 0.321428571428571, 0.0247933884297521, 
    0.644628099173554, 0.190082644628099, 0.0991735537190083, 
    0.0165289256198347, 0.0247933884297521)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Any advice is welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

mydf |> 
  group_by(Company) |> 
  mutate(Share = Value / sum(Value)) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 18 x 4
   Company     Country Value  Share
   <chr>       <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Ferrari     ITA        23 0.288 
 2 Ferrari     ITA        12 0.15  
 3 Ferrari     ITA        45 0.562 
 4 Lamborghini GER        34 0.362 
 5 Lamborghini GER        56 0.596 
 6 Lamborghini GER         3 0.0319
 7 Lamborghini GER         1 0.0106
 8 KTM         AUT         3 0.0214
 9 KTM         AUT        12 0.0857
10 KTM         AUT        35 0.25  
11 KTM         AUT        45 0.321 
12 KTM         AUT        45 0.321 
13 SEAT        ESP         3 0.0248
14 SEAT        ESP        78 0.645 
15 SEAT        ESP        23 0.190 
16 SEAT        ESP        12 0.0992
17 SEAT        ESP         2 0.0165
18 SEAT        ESP         3 0.0248
```